# why Gamma inverse is the conjugate prior of normal distribution?

Tags: regression, bayesian, normal-distribution, bayesian-optimization, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am trying to understand Bayesian regression. Then in Wikipedia [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression), it is written that by using the following relation
[image]

we get the Gamma inverse as follow for the conjugate prior

[image]

But, based on my calculation the following equation is not correct

$(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)= (y-X\hat{\beta})^T(y-X\hat{\beta})+(\beta
 -\hat{\beta})^T(X^TX)(\beta-\hat{\beta})$

In the simplest case, if one put  $\hat{\beta}=0$,

then the equality does not satisfied and the factor  $-2yX^T\beta$ is missing.

Do I miss something?

Comment: $\hat\beta$ is not free for choosing, it is the least square estimator, which explains why Pythagore's identity works in this case and none other.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I thought any $\hat{\beta}$ could have worked.